# Nim-lang: OOP features supported?

Tags: oop, nim-lang

While learning basics of Nim-lang,
I have read that the OOP is minimalistic in Nim;
But I would like to know what features are exactly supported?

> Like:
>
> - Over-ride.
> - Over-load (not supported by PHP yet, 2022).
> - Multi-inheritance (except C++, not supported by any language?).
> - Generics.
> - Classes.
> - Namespaces.
> - Import-as/from-namespace (or Include-file-content like C/C++).
> - Custom type-defs (name aliases).
> - Custom operator implementation(s).
> - Traits (saw only in PHP, if this is even OOP?).

Answer (score 2):

BTW, most of the items on this list aren't OOP specific or even related to the OOP paradigm

However, Nim **does** support:

- Over-ride.
- Over-load.
- Generics.
- Import-as/from-namespace (or Include-file-content like C/C++).
- Custom type-defs (name aliases).
- Custom operator implementation(s).

Nim does not have:

- Multi-inheritance.
- Traits.

Nim weakly supports:

- Classes.

  > Where Polymorphism only really works on `ref` types.
- Namespaces.

  > This should be in not-supported list,
  > but you can force it to use an empty type as the first argument,
  > or store everything in a variable and don't export anything.

Comment: By mentioning both "Import-as/from-namespace" and "Include-file-content like C/C++", it's unclear which Nim supports?

Comment: It supports both. You can import the exported routines/types using `import` and include a file as well using `include`